# In Keras(Deep learning library), RepeatVector + TimeDistributed = Error?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

Hi I'm a beginner keras.

I'm making some model.

step 1. Input batch and word list, (BATCH_SIZE, WORD_INDEX_LIST)
step 2. Get word embeddings each words (BATCH_SIZE, WORD_LENGTH, EMBEDDING_SIZE)
step 3. Average each each word embeddings in each batch. (BATCH_SIZE, EMBEDDING_SIZE)
step 4. Repeat vector N,  (BATCH_SIZE, N, EMBEDDING_SIZE)
step 5. Apply Dense Layer each time step

So, I write code.

```
MAX_LEN = 20 ( = WORD_INDEX_LIST)

 step 1
layer_target_input = Input(shape=(MAX_LEN,), dtype="int32", name="layer_target_input")


# step2
layer_embedding = Embedding(input_dim = n_symbols+1, output_dim=vector_dim,input_length=MAX_LEN, 
                                                 name="embedding", weights= [embedding_weights],trainable = False)
encoded_target = layer_embedding(layer_target_input)


# step 3
encoded_target_agg = KL.core.Lambda( lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=1) )(encoded_target)


#step 4
encoded_target_agg_repeat = KL.RepeatVector( MAX_LEN)(encoded_target_agg)



# step 5
layer_annotated_tahn = KL.Dense(output_dim=50, name="layer_tahn") 
layer_annotated_tahn_td = KL.TimeDistributed(layer_annotated_tahn) (encoded_target_agg_repeat)

model = KM.Model(input=[layer_target_input], output=[ layer_annotated_tahn_td])

r = model.predict({ "layer_target_input":dev_targ}) # dev_targ = (2, 20, 300)
```

But, when i run this code, 
result is bellow.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 127, in <module>
    r = model.predict({ "layer_target_input":dev_targ})
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.0.7-py2.7.egg/keras/engine/training.py", line 1180, in predict
    batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.0.7-py2.7.egg/keras/engine/training.py", line 888, in _predict_loop
    outs[i][batch_start:batch_end] = batch_out
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (30,20,50) into shape (2,20,50)
```

why batch size is changed?
What I have wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `Lambda` operator. In your case it takes a tensor of shape `(batch_size, max_len, embedding_size)` and is expected to produce a tensor of shape `(batch_size, embedding_size)`. However, the `Lambda` op doesn't know what transformation you apply internally, and therefore during the graph compilation mistakenly assumes that the shape doesn't change, therefore assuming that the output shape is `(batch_size, max_len, embedding_size)`. The `RepeastVector` that follows expects the input to be two-dimensional, but never asserts that it is the case. The way it produces the expected shape is `(batch_size, num_repetitions, in_shape[1])`. Since `Lambda` mistakenly reported its shape as `(batch_size, max_len, embedding_size)`, `RepeatVector` now reports its shape as `(batch_size, num_repetitions, max_len)` instead of expected `(batch_size, num_repetitions, embedding_size)`. `num_repetitions` in your case is the same as `max_len`, so `RepeastVector` reports its shape as `(batch_size, max_len, max_len)`. The way `TimeDistributed(Dense)` works is:

```
Reshape((-1, input_shape[2]))
Dense()
Reshape((-1, input_shape[1], num_outputs))
```

By now `input_shape[2]` is mistakenly assumed to be `max_len` instead of `embedding_size`, but the actual tensor that is given has correct shape of `(batch_size, max_len, embedding_size)`, so what ends up happening is:

```
Reshape((batch_size * embedding_size, max_len))
Dense()
Reshape((batch_size * embedding_size / max_len, max_len, num_outputs))
```

In your case `batch_size * embedding_size / max_len` happens to be `2 * 300 / 20 = 30`, that's where your wrong shape comes from.

**To fix it**, you need to explicitly tell `Lambda` the shape you want it to produce:

```
encoded_target_agg = KL.core.Lambda( lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=1), output_shape=(vector_dim,))(encoded_target)
```

Comment: It's a perfect explanation and answer.
It could help to solve my problem.
Thank you very!!